# How do I tell if a conference is legitimate?

Tags: conference

My paper has recently been accepted to the Academy of Finance's annual conference. This organization is hosted under MBAA international. A lot of the heads of the organization are professors at reputable universities but don't have many publications. I did not have to pay anything to attend the conference or submit the paper. How can I tell if this conference is legitimate?

Comment: Can you define "illegitimate conference"?

Comment: Essentially, if I put this on my resume will it be well-regarded. I am an early career researcher so I don't want to inadvertently get myself laughed out of the room.

Comment: You informally ask around your professional network.  If you lack a professional network, you probably have more serious problems beyond knowing what conferences are legitimate.

Comment: I guess you are in a field where conference proceedings value much more than journal publications, say, CS. Then you should know the list of standard top conferences and try to get there. Everything not "top" is probably not good for your CV.

Comment: Sometimes, people attend conferences just because their buddies, ahem, colleagues from other countries are going there as well and the place is nice. I doubt you'd be laughed out of the room under any circumstances unless you decide to actually boast about that for whatever reason... which is not a great idea in the first place. Absolute worst case scenario is it being a predatory conference - there are people who went there and survived - not that the waste of resources is warranted. Otherwise, @AlexanderWoo is veeery much on point.